# Jquery selecionar todos os elementos que contenham o atributo data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Olá, gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de buscar todos os elementos existentes em uma página que contenham o atributo `data-id` assim como eu consigo fazer quando quero pegar uma tag nativa do HTML. por exemplo, se eu executo no DOM do Google Chrome o código `$('div')` ele me lista todos os elementos existentes no documento e que são tag div.

Existe algum tipo de código semelhante a `$('[data-id=*]')`?

Answer (score 0):

Acabei testando, e descobri que se for executado o código buscando o atributo sem referenciar o valor do mesmo ele retorna todos os elementos que contenham aquele atributo, Assim: `$('[data-id]')`